# How to add more users in SSH server

Tags: linux, ssh, debian

How do I add more users in an SSH server and lock them down to a certain folder? I know probably need to add it in the `/etc/ssh/` file directory but I don't know what to change in there. I'm using OpenSSH on a Linux Mint/Debian build

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you mean by locking down to a folder, but I think you're talking about permissions here.

[Here](https://www.guru99.com/file-permissions.html) is a great piece describing permissions in Linux and how to manage them.

You can add a new user using this command:

```
adduser username
```

Once the user has been added, you can assign the relevant permissions.

Comment: // I'm not sure what you mean by locking down to a folder // . The OP probably meant "chroot"ed environment. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chroot